# Sync Music but Manually Manage Videos on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

After switching to wi-fi sync with iOS 5, I've been running into problems with it syncing videos that are already on the device. It slows things down too much, so I thought I'd try manually syncing videos. This also has the advantage of not having to keep videos in my iTunes, I could just drag them from my network file server, saving space on my MacBook.

I did a bit of research and found [Apple HT1535: Managing content manually on iPhone, iPad, and iPod](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1535), which says (emphasis mine):

> Even when you have enabled manual management, you can still sync some content automatically. Select any content tab, such as Video, to enable automatic syncing for that type of content.

That sounds like what I want to do: manually manage video, but select music for auto-syncing. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I followed the steps in the article, but any time I try to select the sync option in the Music tab, it deselects the *Manually manage* option. This is true for the opposite as well, which they describe in the article: manually manage music, but automatically sync video. Selecting *Sync Video* deselects *Manually Manage*.

Is there actually a way to do this in iTunes, or is the Apple article simply wrong and I should just add it to my list of awful things about iTunes?

Comment: Have you considered using a 3rd-Party video playback app that accepts files via iTunes document sharing?